# Get search results from Last.fm API using Node and Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, api

I am trying to use [node-lastfmapi track.search](https://github.com/maxkueng/node-lastfmapi#lfmtracksearchparams-callbackerr-results) method. I am able to get the results but I am unsure on how to display them on front end using Angular. I am using mongoDB for database and have created a schema for a particular search result that user wants to select and wants to save. But before that,the user needs to see the search results. So how can I display these results queried from a 3rd party API by Express.js ?

This is the code I have written so far

```
 app.post('/api/shows', function(req, res, next) {
    var trackName = req.body.trackName;  //search bar which gets trackName user enters
lfm.track.search({
    'track' : trackName
}, function (err, track) {
       if(!track.album.title)
{
              return res.send(404, { message: req.body.trackName + ' was not found.' });

}
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I create simple code snippet for searching in lastfmapi and send results as json in Express.

```
var LastfmAPI = require('lastfmapi');

var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

var lfm = new LastfmAPI({
   //you keys here
});

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.post('/api/shows', function(req, res, next) {
    var trackName = req.body.trackName;
    console.log('get req');

    lfm.track.search({ 'track' : trackName }, function (err, track) {

        res.json(track);
    });
});


console.log('Start listen! on port: ' + port);
app.listen(port);
```

If you want save some results from lfm api response in MongoDb create your own mongoose model and use them in my snippet.

Also I did know why you add AngularJs in your question. Anyways you cant use $resource https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource to get data from resful api in your frontend app.

Comment: The last line is not clear. Can I use $resource ? Because eventually I need these search results to appear on the page and the user should select which need to be saved. That's why Angular , because it should be able to retrieve search results and display them

Comment: @thetechfreak, you need just understand client server architecture. Try implement using something basic like jquery, than use something more abstract like angular.

Comment: @thetechfreak, You need just 3 methods for you api.
1. (GET) find all track in lastfm by query.
2. (POST) Save fav track to db.
3. (GET) Get all fav tracks.